# Подключение EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server

Пытаюсь подключить EntityFramework к проекту. Установил LocalDB. Но при подключении фрэймворка не создается файл app.config.
Также после включения миграций и ее добавление выводит ошибку :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
> Во время запуска экземпляра LocalDB произошла ошибка: ошибка запуска
> процесса SQL Server.

(Хотя sql server запущен)

Как решить проблему?

Comment: У вас в тексте ошибки прямо написано, что делать. Перевести с английского?

Comment: вам надо указать строку соединения такую, по которой можно подключиться к серверу